# Node.js how to save data from terminal

Tags: node.js, terminal

I finally managed to work functionating api with node.js. Is there a way to save the tables I get from the other system via the api? preferable in json format. Right now I only see them in the terminal but I would like to have the option to save them in a folder of my choice for later use.Is there any universal code out there for that?

Comment: you can write the data in a file on your filesystem with the fs library

Comment: can I just put it into a json file with fs.writeFile() and it will automaticly put it in json format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

You can use the [fs library](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to save the data in a file on your filesystem

Here an example

#### write JSON

Adjust the path in  `fs.writeFileSync('student-2.json', data);` the first param and you need write access to the directory.

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

let student = { 
    name: 'Mike',
    age: 23, 
    gender: 'Male',
    department: 'English',
    car: 'Honda' 
};
 
let data = JSON.stringify(student);
fs.writeFileSync('student-2.json', data);
```

#### read JSON

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('student.json');
let student = JSON.parse(rawdata);
console.log(student);
```

Comment: thanks for the effort. It didnt work on first try but they never do anyways ^^. Im going to keep trying later and might come back with some questions.

Comment: @IVnoobSuck okay :) probably something with the path `~/` home directory should work

Comment: just tried it again. Was pretty easy thanks..Since we are at it is there a way to save the tables in a more visible appeasing way? The data is in json format alright but its written in one line side by side.

Comment: I don't think that it is necessary how the visible appeasing is. With the strucuture you have you can easily process the data to display it as a table or something in the html in client side and this is the important part, that you have all the informations and it's easy to process them

Comment: You are right. Thanks again for the help and the quick responses